# Total Relativistic Energy of Massive Body

Tags: special-relativity, energy, kinematics

I have 2 different expressions for the relativistic energy of a body and I'm trying to link them both:

The first one is given by
$$E=\sqrt{(mc^2)^2+(pc)^2},$$
with $m$ the mass and $p$ the momentum.

The second one is given by the mass energy $mc^2$ together with the kinetic energy $T$:
$$E = mc^2 + T.$$

I also have that $$T=p^2/2m,$$ but if I substitute that in the first expression I don't obtain the second expression. Can someone explain why?

Comment: $T$ above is the relativistic kinetic energy. You obtain the classical expression when $mc <<p$.

Comment: @ValterMoretti This should be the other way round: $p\ll mc$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can derive the second expression from the the first one,
but only approximately, not exactly.

$$\begin{align}
E&=\sqrt{(mc^2)^2+(pc)^2} \\
 &=mc^2\sqrt{1+\frac{p^2}{m^2c^2}} \\
 &\approx mc^2\left(1+\frac{p^2}{2m^2c^2}\right) \\
 &=mc^2+\frac{p^2}{2m}.
\end{align}$$

The approximation done in the 3rd line is
$$\sqrt{1+x}\approx 1+\frac{x}{2}$$
which is valid only if $x\ll 1$.
In your case this means $p\ll mc$,
which essentially is the non-relativistic
case (bodies with slow velocity, much smaller than $c$).

Remember, the relation $T=\frac{p^2}{2m}$
is from Newtonian mechanics. and thus becomes wrong
for larger velocity (i.e. not much smaller than $c$).